# React Native firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

How to set the `firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier` in react native using firebase web method to verify phone number and authenticate by receiving OTP on device.Tried with some Methods but not working on mobile.

Code for react native using Web Method:

```
var appVerifier = firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier;
// window.recaptchaVerifier =
//   new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');

firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber('+919843191338', appVerifier)
    .then(function (confirmationResult) {
        Alert.alert(confirmationResult);
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // Error; SMS not sent
        // ...
    });
```

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040495/using-firebase-phone-number-auth-with-react-native

Answer (score 0):

You can enable auto verification by enabling SafetyNet API

Check this for detailed information:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth